# Catkin and Qt_ros. How to build

Tags: c++, catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm a bit lost with the integration of Qt with ROS. I have to make a few custom interfaces for my university project (a nifty robot that do cool stuff) and I was thinking about using Qt to make them since we already have a lot of experience with Qt C++ in my team.

The problem is, my workspace is using catkin and the package qt_ros (with the node roscreate-qt-pkg) seems to create files that are made for rosbuilder. By example, it create a manifest.xml (wich I think is deprecated in groovy) and the CMakeLists.txt is really different from the ones I get from catkin-package. So, my node is not built at all when I execute catkin_make. How am I suppose to do it?

I really like ROS and all his tools, but if I can't create my interfaces quickly we will have to switch to another technology or think about an alternative to talk to ROS from another application that contains our interface : (.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57227/catkin-and-qt_ros.-how-to-build/) by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2013-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on 2013-03-05**:
Do I have to make this : "Simply make in place (native compile) or use rosbuild2 to cross-compile with mingw"?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In `Groovy`, most of the building tools used in previous distributions are still valid. So you can build your stuff that you have been able to build with `catkin`, and also build the packages that you made with `qt_ros`, and run them. Upon runtime, build system used should not matter afaik so that you can mix them.

Wiki pages of `qt_ros` neither specifies that they don't work on Groovy nor  buildsystem to be used. Considering that it worked pretty well for me with `rosbuild` on `fuerte`, I recommend to use it first with `rosbuild` (run `rosmake`).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phbou72](https://answers.ros.org/users/4334/phbou72/) on 2013-03-06**:
What is better : reconfigure my catkin workspace to only use rosbuild instead or try to mix the both of them? I need to reuse code and messages I have in my catkin workspace since my nodes will eventually speak together.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-03-06**:
I updated my answer since it wasn't clear, but yes mixing them shouldn't be a problem afaik.